# Scrapy crawlspider rules

Tags: python, scrapy, rules

The basic spider works.
Then I converted it to a CrawlSpider and rules, unfortunately now the spider doesn’t work any more.

The basic spider is tested on a product detail page:
https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi395939/ah-kleintje-boerenkool
Then it gets the items as specified.

My interest is to use the CrawlSpider to go thru all the bonus articles https://www.ah.nl/bonus
Going to the product detail pages and get the specified information.

1. How can I fix my code so the spider will work again?
2. Can some one explain what I’m doing wrong with the rules
3. I would like to exclude also  response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'product-sidebar__products')]")
   If this “anderen kochten ook” (in English: “other customers both these products”) is present at the product detail page 
   https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi160917/ah-verse-pesto-groen here it is present 
   https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi220252/swiffer-vloerreiniger-navul-stofdoekjes here it not present

I have tried many things but can't get my head around the rules

```
class ahSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'ah'
    allowed_domains = ['ah.nl']  # geen url neer zetten alleen domain name
    start_urls = ['https://www.ah.nl']

    # "anderen kochten ook" "in English: “other customers both these products"
    # response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'product-sidebar__products')]")

    rules = [
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/bonus'), deny=('/allerhandebox/', '/allerhande/', '/winkels/', '/acties/', '/klantenservice/', '/zakelijk/', '/bezorgbundel/', '/vakslager/')), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/producten/product/[0-9]+/[0-9]+'),), callback='parse_items'),
    ]

    #def parse(self, response):
    def parse_items(self, response):
        items = AhItem()

        product_name = response.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'line-clamp--active')]//text()").extract_first()

        items['product_name']           = product_name
        yield items
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. `doesn't work anymore` is never self explanatory. What are the errors your get ? Or what is the result and how does it differ from your expectations ? You should edit your question and add more info to get a better chance for a fast and pertinent answer. Moreover, please avoid asking several questions in a single one: use separate posts. Have a good time on SO.

Answer (score 1):

1. The main problem seems to come from the expression '[0-9]+/[0-9]+'. The links on the page have product-detail links in the style of 'https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi460830/edet-ultra-soft-tp-magnolia-4-laags', 'https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi210145/heineken-premium-pilsener'. If you change your expression to `allow=('/producten/product/')` these product-detail links are not filtered out anymore.
2. Explained under 1
3. You can include something like the following under the parse_items-method:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
others = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"product-sidebar__products")]')
if others:
  raise DropItem("'others also bought' present on the product_detail page")
```

Comment: Hi Wim, 
Thank for your replay! Your first solution works! It give output now.

Comment: I'm struggling with you 3 point. It is not working.Could you give more details?

I also want to only extract the products 
response.xpath("//div[@data-testid='bonus-lane--AH']")
Or exclude products mentioned with similar xpath.
How can I do this?

Thanks for your help on for hand!

Comment: The idea is to identify whether there is a value in the xpath, and if so, to drop the item. My solution doesn't work indeed, because that part is loaded dynamically. The easiest here is probably to check where that data is coming from, and try to figure out based on what you can drop the item or not. To limit the results in the LinkExtractor you can add this: `restrict_xpaths='//div[@data-testid="bonus-lane--AH"]'`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your reaction. I'm not getting any errors just an empty file.
Hopefully you can give some feedback on the code?

Thanks on for hand!
Rob